# Create objects dynamically according to class files in specified project folder

Tags: progress-4gl

We have a folder with many classes that inherit from the same base class. Their names are formatted like this:

- firsttypesubclass_1.cls
- firsttypesubclass_2.cls
- firsttypesubclass_3.cls
- secondtypesubclass_1.cls
- secondtypesubclass_2.cls

The program should scan this class folder and create a temp-table with the class-name prefix and count (f.ex "firsttypesubclass" and count=3):

```
DEFINE PUBLIC TEMP-TABLE TT_AllSubClasses NO-UNDO
   FIELD Name AS INT /* f.ex "firsttypesubclass" */
   FIELD Name AS INT /* f.ex "firsttypesubclass" */
.
```

Then we need to create new instances dynamically according to the found classes in a loop like this:

```
DEF VAR newInstance AS CLASS myBaseClass NO-UNDO.
newInstance = DYNAMIC-NEW TT_AllSubClasses.Name + "_" + STRING(1)(123123) NO-ERROR.
```

Is there any convenient way to list the class names in the folder? Or is it possibly to get all classes that inherit from the baseclass? I'm thinking about using the file system for checking up the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reach out to the file system and list all class files in the relevant folder. If at runtime the source code is not available, you should base your code on R-code. `INPUT FROM OS-DIR` is your friend there.

If you are mixing procedural and class based R-code in those relevant folders, you'll also have to verify if the R-code is from a procedure or a class:

`RCODE-INFO:FILE-NAME = cFileName .`

`IF RCODE-INFO:IS-CLASS THEN ...`

OpenEdge 11.6 has more reflection features. But there is no functionality that lists all child classes of a given base class. As the ABL does not have a fixed library scheme for classes (like C#), that would probably also be difficult for Progress to implement.

Comment: I will try this. Seems that there's also a good tutorial on Progress' site about listing the files in specific folder with `INPUT FROM OS-DIR` here: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P21640